# C# Retrieving the absolute value closest to 0 from a sum in a list

Tags: c#, linq

What I'm trying to do is get the `Time` where `Math.Abs(A + B + C)` is closest to 0 for **each** `ID`. It's quite hefty. I have a list (that I got from a CSV file) that kind of looks like this:

```
        |------------|------------|-------|-------|-------|
        |    Time    |     ID     |   A   |   B   |   C   |
        |------------|------------|-------|-------|-------|
        |    100     |     1      |   1   |   2   |   2   |
        |------------|------------|-------|-------|-------| 
        |    100     |     2      |   3   |   4   |   3   |
        |------------|------------|-------|-------|-------| 
        |    200     |     1      |   1   |   0   |   3   |
        |------------|------------|-------|-------|-------| 
        |    200     |     2      |   1   |   2   |   0   |
        |------------|------------|-------|-------|-------|
```

I have the following code, and while it it not complete yet, it technically prints the value that I want. However when I debug it, it doesn't seem to be looping through the IDs, but does it all in one loop. My idea was that I could get all the distinct `ID`s, then go through the distinct `Time` for each, put them all in a temporary list, then just use `Aggregate` to get the value closest to 0. But I feel there should be a more efficient approach than this. Is there a quicker LINQ function I can use to achieve what I want?

```
for (int i = 0; i < ExcelRecords.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().Count(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < ExcelRecords.Select(y => y.Time).Distinct().Count(); j++)
            {
                List<double> test = new List<double>();

                var a = ExcelRecords[j].a;
                var b = ExcelRecords[j].b;
                var c = ExcelRecords[j].c;
                test.Add(Math.Abs(pitch + yaw + roll));

                Console.WriteLine(Math.Abs(pitch + yaw + roll));
            }
        }
```

Comment: As a side note.
Assuming your `ExcelRecords.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().Count()` does not change throughout the loop (which is this case it doesn't) you should calculate that before the loop and place it in a variable. This because it will evaluate the expression every loop and thus perform the Select, Distinct, and Count over the entire collection for every single row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using explicit for loops like this is throwing the power and flexibility of LINQ out the window. LINQ's power comes from enumerators which can be used on their own or in conjunction with a `foreach` loop.

You are also doing way more work than necessary using `Distinct` to first get a list and then using that list to selectively group the rows into batches. This is what `GroupBy` was designed for.

```cs
var times = ExcelRecords.GroupBy((row) => row.Id)
                        .Select((g) => g.Aggregate((min, row) => Math.Abs(row.a + row.b + row.c) < Math.Abs(min.a + min.b + min.c) ? row : min).Time)
                        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you! It totally makes sense, I also felt there was too much going on with that loop. May I ask what the `.Time` in the end does in the Select statement?

Comment: @Neicy It gets the `Time` property of the row that is returned by `g.Min` so you end up with a list of the values that appear in the "Time" column.

Comment: @Abion47 I seem to be having a problem where `.Time` is not being recognized as a property by the Select statemet

Comment: @Neicy Edited with a different approach that uses `Aggregate` instead.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! That was also enough impetus to also study LINQ properly haha

Comment: I believe you can have a more readable solution by using [MoreLINQ](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ)'s [MinBy](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/MinBy.cs) method

Comment: @Jonathan Absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most readable way would be to group by `Id`, order each group and select the first `Time` from each:

```
var times = ExcelRecords.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderBy(item => Math.Abs(item.A + item.B + item.C)))
    .Select(grp => grp.First().Time);
```

[Working Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/V5EGhG)